# Use of || {} in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I saw something like this in Javascript :

```
   function name (secret) {
          secret = secret || {};
```

i can't find anywhere what exactly means **secret = secret || {};**

Is that mean create global variable with value of passed argument or an object?

When do you use it? When there is no argument passed?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

### What it means

If the variable `secret` is falsy (*one of the following*):

- `false`
- `0`
- `''` (empty string)
- `null`
- `undefined`
- `NaN`

..then set it to `{}` (an empty object - it's the same as `new Object()`).

---

### Alternative code

It could also be written as this:

```
if (!secret) secret = {};
```

But as it's longer most people prefer the above.

---

### Why?

This solution is useful as javascript has no default function parameters.

For example an example in PHP could look like this:

```
<?php
    function foo($bar = 'default') {
        echo $bar;
    }
?>
```

and in JS that *could* be

```
function foo(bar) {
    bar = bar || 'default';
    console.log(bar);
}
foo(); //default
foo(NaN); //default
foo(undefined); //default
foo(null); //default
foo(false); //default
foo(0); //default
foo(''); //default
foo('something'); //something
foo(12); //12
foo(1.2); //1.2
```

---

### What if I *only* want to set a default if nothing else has been set?

If you **only** want to check for no value (no falsy values), then you can use the [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) function in JS:

```
function foo(bar) {
    if (typeof bar == 'undefined') bar = 'default';
    console.log(bar);
}
foo(); //default
foo(undefined); //default
foo(NaN); //NaN
foo(null); //null
foo(false); //false
foo(0); //0
foo(''); //(empty string)
foo('something'); //something
foo(12); //12
foo(1.2); //1.2
```

Comment: Actually, it will also set `secret` to `{}` if `secret` is any "falsy" value (0, empty string, `false`, etc.)

Comment: Don't you mean _"if `secret` **is** empty ..."_? Also, the `typeof` test is _not_ equivalent, since it doesn't handle anything except `undefined`. (The irony, of course, is that `{}` is also a falsy value, so it will reassign `secret` to a new empty object even when it is an empty object.)

Comment: @TedHopp Yes - you're of course completely correct - I've revised my answer.

Comment: Better, but please also fix the "isn't" (at the start of the answer).

Comment: @TedHopp Oh yes, I must be tired as I didn't see your previous answer. I've tested with `{}` and `[]` and both return their respectable values in the original example (in my Chrome 22 at least), so are you sure that they're falsy? (or is it only falsy according to the standard, and isn't implemented in Chrome?)

Comment: Good. I also must have been too tired when I wrote that. Of course, empty lists and arrays are truthy values, not falsy. For the record, the falsy values are: `null`, `undefined`, 0, `""`, and `NaN`.