# Can anyone tell me what this javascript might be doing

Tags: javascript

So I am looking over a project which includes the following line of javascript:

```
window.negotiationApp = window.negotiationApp || {};
```

Can anyone explain might be going on with this line of code?

**Update**
So now that I understand what this line of code is doing, my question maybe unique in asking the following:

There is no negotiationApp object in the javascript code. window.negotiationApp will always be set to an empty object, it seems the developer is really just using this as a namespace or container for other objects. Is this a common javascript practice?

Comment: Thanks for the quick answers guys, it looks like the developer that wrote this code never creates a negotiationApp object and so basically its usage seems to be that of a namespace in his code.

Comment: The same as `window.negotiationApp || (window.negotiationApp = {})` :)

Comment: More duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13268848/218196, http://stackoverflow.com/q/4087543/218196, http://stackoverflow.com/q/13016235/218196, http://stackoverflow.com/q/2802055/218196, http://stackoverflow.com/q/9604865/218196 -- Looks like we have to clean this up a bit.

Comment: @FelixKling, I updated my question as there may be one aspect of my question that makes this unique, if not I will be happy to delete the question if this is a stackoverflow best practice, but I don't want people that took the time to properly answer this question to lose their points...

Comment: I'd just leave it be, Brian. No harm in a few more quality answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it makes sure that `window.negotiationApp` is set. If `window` does not have this property then it initializes it to be `{}` (an empty object), otherwise, it does nothing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the developer that wrote this code does not ever create an negotiationApp object so it is always initialized as an empty object ({}), is this a common practice to achieve a namespace in javascript?

Comment: I do not know about how common this is, but most of the code that I have seen uses objects like this to put all the code's functionality in.

Answer (score 2):

It's an idiom that basically means, if `window.negotiationApp` doesn't exist, set it to `{}`. You might do that so future info doesn't return undefined or something.

Answer (score 2):

Ensures `window.negotiationApp` object is not undefined.

```
window.negotiationApp = window.negotiationApp || {};
```

Means if `window.negotiationApp` is defined then use it or assign `window.negotiationApp` an empty object.

```
if(window.negotiationApp) {
  window.negotiationApp = window.negotiationApp;
}
else {
  window.negotiationApp = {};
}
```

Answer (score 2):

since this variable is set on the global scope, it makes sure not to override an existing one if there is any.

so it basically says, if there is already a `negotiationApp` variable defined - use it, if not create a new one.